# How do I contribute new files to the KhanAcademy Github?

Tags: khan-academy

How do I commit new files to the khan-api repository? I created a simple MVC PHP example client (As the current php test client was quite confusing).

e.g. This is how it looks now:

```
    if (isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login']) {
        $this->login();
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_GET['oauth_token']) {
        $this->doOathAuthentication();

    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['logged_in']) && $_GET['logged_in']) {
        $this->mainPage();
    }
    else {
        $this->defaultPage();
    }
```

Which makes it a bit easier to understand :-)

Answer (score 0):

We're happy to accept pull requests on Github!  We don't use PHP much so I'm not sure how quickly we'll be able to review it, but if you make sure to mention exactly what you're improving over the existing client, that will help us evaluate the pull request.

Comment: I don't have an SVN client on this new machine. Basically the current php_example_client is just one php file (kind of spaghetti like) with the Controller/View all in the same file. I just cleaned it up to make the logic easier to understand for people who would like to start using the KA_client in PHP. Can I just e-mail it to you? :)

Comment: Sorry; since these are example clients, it's not a very high priority for us to support them, so we'd really prefer a pull request as that makes it easy for us to review.  Github has a [web editing interface](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flow-in-the-browser/), though, which you may be able to use to create the pull request.